# How to upgrade from 21.04 Hirsute to 22.04 Jammy?

Tags: upgrade, updates, 21.04, 22.04

I have a personal system, which I would like to upgrade, preferably without having to do a fresh install.

So far, I have tried to use the Software Updater GUI, which prompted me to update to 21.10. However after clicking update, it hasn't followed up with any prompts or anything that I could see.

I have also tried to use `do-release-upgrade` and `do-release-upgrade -p` both of which has failed stating that my release is not supported anymore.

I have tried to use `do-release-upgrade -d` as well, which has failed stating that:

> Upgrades to the development release are only available from the latest supported release.

After which, I've looked for ways to update an end of life distribution and found [this](https://serverfault.com/a/640092). However editing my `/etc/apt/sources.list` hasn't yielded any results either.

What can I do to update my system besides a fresh install?

Comment: There is no direct path to upgrade. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) might work.

Comment: You weren't specific as to what system you have, ie. desktop? server? etc.  I keep a system for each *supported* release & when 21.04 reached EOL & i didn't need it anymore, I *upgraded via re-install* it to what was Ubuntu *jammy* at that time, and used the installation method where none of my files were touched, my additional packages (ie. *manually installed*) were re-installed and that install became *jammy* (now 22.04) install box & is now a *jammy* support box too.  You can re-install without loosing data or additional packages if you're using a desktop system (key is don't format)

Comment: Managed to upgrade to 21.10 by using the upgrade tarball, upgrading to 22.04 should be straight forward now.